# how to change the language in swift for the users location

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults, cllocationmanager

Im trying to change the language in the users app like this:

```
    userDefaults.setObject(["en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
```

NOTE: (iPhone language is set to french)

But I am running into some issues. Number one it only kicks in after the app restarts, and number two I can't get the current location in english even after the iPhone restarts. Heres the code I'm using for getting the users current location:

```
func displayLocationInfo (placemark: CLPlacemark) {

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    // Find current location
    self.currentLocation = placemark.locality
    self.realCurrentLocation = placemark.locality

    // Find current state
    self.currentState = placemark.administrativeArea
    self.realCurrentState = placemark.administrativeArea

    // Find current country
    self.currentCountry = placemark.country
    self.realCurrentCountry = placemark.country

}
```

I keep getting Estas-Unis for the currentCountry and it should be United States because it is set in english?? Is there anyway around these issues without using NSLocalizedString!? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should think about whether you really, really want to do this. Imagine American or European tourists on holiday in China, and suddenly they can't understand anything their app tries to tell them.

Comment: No I do not want to change the user facing text I just want the code in the background to be in english so my whole database can be english and when your language settings are changed, Estats-Unis will not resonate with United States

Comment: Same problem here, but at least, Apple is going to fix this issue by adding a new function to the Geocoder reverse location :  ` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/2908779-reversegeocodelocation `